# Why doesn't the icon change in the launcher when I change the .desktop file?

Tags: 14.04, unity

I'm a bit of a tinkerer and changed my most commonly used application icons to have my own steam-punk theme.

The only application whose icon I couldn't get to change was [qBitTorrent](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12339929/).

The `.desktop` file<s>s</s> are only present in `/usr/share/applications` to make them available to all users and `~/.local/share/applications/` has been verified not to contain any desktop files.

*Can anyone shed a light on why this is happening?*  (And give some direction how to change that icon?)

[image: SteamPunk Launcher]

For the ones out there who don't know about SteamPunk: I want to change the ugly blue icon...  **;-)**

**Some more info:**

```
$ lsattr /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
-------------e-- /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop

$ lsattr /usr/share/pixmaps/Steampunk-Vlc-Audio-Player-Icon-Mkii.png 
-------------e-- /usr/share/pixmaps/Steampunk-Vlc-Audio-Player-Icon-Mkii.png
```

Now that I've got qTox running myself (with a little bit of help from @JacobVlijm) and no one has given me any ideas for qBittorrent, I'm adding a bounty...

#### Note:

**I'm not looking to change the icon using the `~/.local/share/applications/` override but for all users in `/usr/share/applications/` or any other system-wide setting!**

Comment: Hi Fabby, How did you install it? I downloaded it here: https://github.com/tux3/qTox, unpacked it (just an executable), ran it and it created a `qtox.desktop` file locally. I then changed the icon without a problem. see https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/fabby/1.png and https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/fabby/2.png

Comment: `apt-cache policy qtox-unity` noteworthy output: `500 https://pkg.tox.chat/debian/ nightly/release amd64 Packages`

Comment: @kos: It's my own theme, sorry...  Just a bunch of icons converted to 128x128 in `/usr/share/pixmaps` and then a bunch of manually edited `.desktop` files... That's *why* I'm running into trouble...  Doing stuff I'd better not do! **;-)** (as every firefox update needs me to go in and edit the desktop file again.)

Comment: @kos: Yep, and *only in qBittorrent!*  All the others work flawlessly...  **:-(**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that qBittorrent's `.desktop` file sets the icon based on the localization:

```
sed -n '/^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?=.*$/p' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
Icon=qbittorrent
Icon[be]=qbittorrent
Icon[cs]=qbittorrent
Icon[el]=qbittorrent
Icon[en_GB]=qbittorrent
Icon[es]=qbittorrent
Icon[eu]=qbittorrent
Icon[fi]=qbittorrent
Icon[gl]=qbittorrent
Icon[it]=qbittorrent
Icon[ja]=qbittorrent
Icon[lt]=qbittorrent
Icon[nb]=qbittorrent
Icon[pl]=qbittorrent
Icon[pt]=qbittorrent
Icon[pt_BR]=qbittorrent
Icon[ro]=qbittorrent
Icon[ru]=qbittorrent
Icon[sv]=qbittorrent
Icon[uk]=qbittorrent
Icon[vi]=qbittorrent
Icon[zh_TW]=qbittorrent
Icon[en_AU]=qbittorrent
```

So changing the icon set by the first generic `Icon=` entry doesn't help:

[image: screenshot1]

You'll have to set the `Icon=` entry matching your current locale; however since localizing the icon by setting *the very same icon* for each locale is a very silly thing to do in first place, you might as well just change all the `Icon=` entries by running this command (it will create a `qBittorrent.desktop.bak` backup file in `/usr/share/applications`):

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's|^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?=.*$|Icon\1=/path/to/icon|' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
```

```
Insert the path to the icon here-------------------^-----------^
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % sudo sed -i.bak 's|^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?=.*$|Icon\1=/home/user/icon.png|' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop 
user@user-X550CL ~ % sed -n '/^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?=.*$/p' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
Icon=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[be]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[cs]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[el]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[en_GB]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[es]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[eu]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[fi]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[gl]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[it]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[ja]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[lt]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[nb]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[pl]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[pt]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[pt_BR]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[ro]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[ru]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[sv]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[uk]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[vi]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[zh_TW]=/home/user/icon.png
Icon[en_AU]=/home/user/icon.png
```

Or delete the localized `Icon=` entries and change the generic `Icon=` entry by running this command (it will create a `qBittorrent.desktop.bak` backup file in `/usr/share/applications`):

```
sudo sed -i.bak '/^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\=.*$/d; s|^Icon=.*$|Icon=/path/to/icon|'
```

```
Insert the path to the icon here------------------------------^-----------^
```

```
user@user-X550CL ~ % sudo sed -i.bak '/^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\=.*$/d; s|^Icon=.*$|Icon=/path/to/icon|' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
user@user-X550CL ~ % sed -n '/^Icon\(\[[^]]*\]\)\?=.*$/p' /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
Icon=/path/to/icon
```

Or just change the `Icon=` entry matching your current locale by any mean, such as:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/qBittorrent.desktop
```

[image: screenshot2]

Comment: +1, Same here, I knew it existed, never ran into it though. One tiny thing; I'd prefer to edit a local copy as a general rule :).

Comment: @Fabby Yes sorry, I changed it but not fast enough, here's the original if you messed it up using my command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12420131/. That's silly tough, I don't get why setting the same icon for each locale, just don't set anything and let it fall back to the general. -_-

Comment: @kos nice catch!